# Understand Javascript Object In If Statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify this javascript for retrieving place information but I cannot figure out what the if statement is evaluating in the example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

The specific if statement I don't understand what is being evaluated is:

```
if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
```

Comment: All your answers are correct. My problem was understanding the remaining of the code. From what I understand now, it was checking if there was a short_name or long_name in the componentForm of the addressType of the place.address_components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentForm` is an object made at the top of the `<script>` block:

```
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```

To access properties in a JS object, you can use the Array notation when needing a dynamic way to access properties - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Syntax

The `if` statement is testing whether the componentForm object `hasOwnProperty()` or any `prototype` whose key name is equal to the string value inside `addressType`  and if that is true, then grabs that value using the resulting value from `componentForm` as the property accessor into the `place.address_components[i]` object.

```
place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]]
```

`place` - object
`address_components` - array `i` - integer `componentForm` - object `addressType` - string

Answer (score 3):

This will check if `componentForm[addressType]` is not **undefined**, **null**, **empty string**, **0**, **NaN** nor **false**.

Answer (score 1):

if (componentForm[addressType]) {

Evaluates if `componentForm[addressType]` is existing

**Here are some possibilities of `if` condition failing**

```
        0
        null
        ""
        ''
       [].length
       {}.length
       undefined
       false
```

**Here are some cases of `if` condition successful**

```
"string"
"0"
" "
' '
[]
{}
true
```

You can `console.log(componentForm[addressType])` or `alert(componentForm[addressType])` and check which of the above mentioned scenarios are matching.